# Any way to get a hold of a properly initialized wiki parser in the ajax hook of MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

Using `$wgAjaxExportList` in an extension, is it possible to get a hold of a proper wiki parser?

so far I have tried something in the lines of this:

```
    global $wgParser;
    $parserOpts = \ParserOptions::newFromContext(\RequestContext::getMain());
    $wgParser->startExternalParse(null,$parserOpts,OT_HTML);
    $html = $wgParser->internalParse($code);
    $html = $wgParser->replaceLinkHolders($html);
    $html = $wgParser->replaceTransparentTags($html);
    $html = \Sanitizer::normalizeCharReferences($html);
    return $html;
```

However, this does not work properly.

Now i know there is an javascript api for parsing wikicode: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext

But I do not wish to use this, as that would mean I will have to do more than one ajax request.

Is there a better way of parsing wiki text on serverside from an ajax request within an extension?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call all of those internal functions yourself, you should just use `$wgParser->parse()` and pass in the ParserOptions.

Also (and unrelatedly), you should write an API module, `$wgAjaxExportList` is a deprecated interface.